# On Language change civicrm api for participant status change does not work as expected

Tags: participants, language

```
$result1 = civicrm_api3('Participant', 'create', [
        'id' => $participant_id,
        'contact_id' => $contact_id,
        'event_id'   => $event_id,
        'status_id' => "Registered",//已登記
      ]);
```

when I have English enabled in the civicrm, the above API works changes
 status to Registered from Attended
When I have Chinese Language enabled in the civicrm, the above API does not change the status 
In the list of Civicrm Participant Status I found that Participant 
status label is different in Chinese and English(which is obvious)
But how can we determine if the civicrm page is chinese, As I am using 
drupal, In drupal we have

```
global $language;
$lang_code = $language->language;
```

but in civicrm , how can we determine the language selected from the 
dropdown and based on that change status_id to be in chinese.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the label is different in English and Chinese, the above API with `'status_id' => "Registered",` parameter should work fine as it is meant to make the mapping based on `name` and not label.

Anyway, I think you should be able to use id instead of passing the name of the participant status in the api params. Something like -

```
$statusOptions = CRM_Event_BAO_Participant::buildOptions('status_id', 'validate');
...
...your api ...
...
  'status_id' => array_search('Registered', $statusOptions),
```

If the above fails, and you still want to do this by knowing which language is enabled, you can simply use -

```
$currentLanguageLocale = CRM_Core_I18n::getLocale();
```

The variable `$currentLanguageLocale` will hold the locale value of the current language enabled in civi.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to get status_id and use it in Participant Api clearly using above quoted code in the question?

Comment: Have already done that. `array_search('Registered', $statusOptions)` will provide you the id of `Registered` participant status.

Comment: Can I write a custom query to update the Participant Status UPDATE `civicrm_participant` SET `status_id` = '1' WHERE `civicrm_participant`.`id` = 1; will that be work or its a bad idea? and if yes how can I write a custom query in civicrm? @jitendra
?